# isometries in 3 dimensions

Tags: isometry

The 2-dimensional surface of a square can be isometrically transformed into a 3-dimensional cylinder or a cone.
In what other shapes can it be isometrically transformed?
More generally, what is the underlying theory concerning 
isometric transformations of surfaces in 3 dimensions?

Comment: Look up [developable surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface).

Comment: "Surface of a square" should be "surface of a cube", don't you think ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: no, square is meant, or any planar rectangle.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you !

Comment: Another Keyword is "rules surfaces". Among them the one-sheeted hyperboloid and the parabolic hyperboloid.